# How to optimize SQL query with multiple SELECTs from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How can I optimizate this SQL Query?

```
(SELECT SUM (same_field) FROM same_table WHERE other_same_field = '0') AS a,
(SELECT SUM (same_field) FROM same_table WHERE other_same_field = '1') AS b,
(SELECT SUM (same_field) FROM same_table WHERE other_same_field = '2') AS c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to do a pivot in MySQL you can do Aggregate on a Case statement

```
SELECT 
    SUM ( CASE WHEN other_same_field  = 0 THEN same_field ELSE 0 END) as A,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN other_same_field  = 1 THEN same_field ELSE 0 END) as B,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN other_same_field  = 2 THEN same_field ELSE 0 END) as C
FROM same_table
WHERE other_same_field IN (0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Which one is actually better in performance, yours or @FreshPrinceOfSO's query?

Comment: @cawecoy I would expect the perf to be about the same, but they yield different results (1 row, 3 columns) vs (3 rows, 2 columns). The deciding factor would be how you intend to use the results. If you can I would go with FreshPrinceOfSO's since the SQL is cleaner. But if you need it in the format of 3 columns and you can't/or don't want to do the projection on the client then you'd need to go with `SUM(CASE..`

Comment: Thank you ConradFrix and @FreshPrinceOfSO.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you a vertical result.

```
SELECT other_same_field, SUM(same_field)
FROM same_table
WHERE other_same_field IN (0, 1, 2)
GROUP BY other_same_field
```

Comment: The wouldn't match the output of the original statement.

Comment: I still think it's a valid answer on how to optimize the query.